# java twitter4j are tweet ids unique

Tags: java, twitter, unique, twitter4j

Doing some java dev with twitter4j and curious to know if when I make a call to

```
Status tweet = blah blah blah.
long tweetID = tweet.getId(); //Is this unique?
```

I setup a HashSet in order to keep track of tweets I've already received and I have a print statement for duplicates. I was under the impression that Twitter used a 64bit long to generate unique keys but I was unable to find any correlation between the twitter4j tweet id and Twitter's tweet id. Main question is: Are the twitter4j Status tweet ids unique?

[Edit]
Some elaboration, I have a HashSet of Longs

```
HashSet<Long> usedIds = new HashSet<Long>();
//Get new twitter4j Status
if(!usedIds.contains(tweetID)) {
    //this is not a duplicate
    //Place id into set
    usedIds.add(tweetID);
    //do work
} else {
    //This is duplicate and my program is printing stuff
    //From what I've learned this condition should never be met but it is
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for adding the Tweet ID to the HashSet?  Can you also include any other code that reads/writes or otherwise manipulates the HashSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the twitter4j's `Status.getId()` returns the unique ID of the Tweet, as determined by Twitter.  It's not creating it's own IDs.  Perhaps your HashSet is too aggressive with the key space and you're getting a collision, but the `getId` call is going to give you the Tweet's actual ID.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "aggressive" key space handling is?

Comment: How are you instantiating the HashSet you're using?  I just looked at the Twitter4J source -- it's pulling the ID right out of the JSON in the HTTP Response from the Twitter API.  https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/c5079db846c42a144c8fd603a76a5ec4941a7382/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j/internal/json/StatusJSONImpl.java

Comment: private HashSet<Long> usedIds = new HashSet<Long>(); And when I get a new tweet I make a check with usedIds.contains(tweet.getId())